# How to minimize a JQuery UI Portlet by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets

in that link above there are objects called as portlets. the thing i want is how could i make the portlets start as minimized by default.

Is there any possible ways to make it start as minimized in initial view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going directly off of their example source code, then you simply need to update

```
.portlet-content { padding: 0.4em; }
```

to

```
.portlet-content { display:none; padding: 0.4em; }
```

and

```
.prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
```

to

```
.prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick'></span>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$(function() {
    $( ".portlet-header" ).each(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
    $(this).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: While this would work, I'd suggest updating the original code as opposed to adding additional JavaScript to counter-act existing JavaScript.

Comment: its basically just simulating a user click on each portlet, i dont think it would counter-act any existing javascript

Comment: Yes, but why execute more JavaScript when the portlets can be rendered and initialized with the desired effect?

Comment: FWIW, this came in handy as I can't change the code directly. BTW, does anyone know why using toggle() here instead of hide() doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Inspirated by jaredhoyt I am using following:

1. into `<style>` section add
   `.close { display:none; padding: 0.4em; }`
2. into `<script>` section add 
   `$( ".closehead" ).prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick'></span>");`
3. add value **close** into class of the each portlet-content which you want to collapse 
   `<div class="portlet-content close" id="detailed2">`
4. add value **closehead** into class of the each portlet-header for which you want to setup plus thick
   `<div class="portlet-header closehead">Details</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $('#action').parents(".header");
    var c = h.next('.porlets-content');
    var p = h.parent();
    c.slideToggle();
    p.toggleClass('closed');
});
```

"action" is the ID of the HTML element that contains the button to minimize the portlet.

Look at my example below:

```
<div id="action" class="actions">
  <a href="#" class="minimize"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maximize adding on page;

```
<div class="portlet-widgets">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#portlet1"><i class="ion-minus-round"></i></a>
</div>
<div id="portlet1" class="panel-collapse collapse in"></div>
```

Minimize adding on page;

```
<div class="portlet-widgets">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#portlet2" class="collapsed"><i class="ion-minus-round"></i></a>
</div>
<div id="portlet2" class="panel-collapse collapse"></div>
```